# UWP - Unable To Paste Text in the Current Cursor Position

Tags: uwp

I am performing copy and paste operation in multi-line texbox. Paste Method Works good in normal cases but whenever I click Enter Key(Return Key) and then paste the clipboard content it just append the text, there is no space or new line created between the text.

Code Behind:

```
private async void PasteButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataPackageView dataPackageView = Clipboard.GetContent();
    if (dataPackageView.Contains(StandardDataFormats.Text))
    {
        try
        {
            string TextCopied = await dataPackageView.GetTextAsync();
            var selectionIndex = MainTextBox.SelectionStart;
            MainTextBox.Text = MainTextBox.Text.Insert(selectionIndex, TextCopied);
            MainTextBox.SelectionStart = selectionIndex + TextCopied.Length;
            MainTextBox.Focus(FocusState.Pointer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog(ex.Message);
            await md.ShowAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:
     `<TextBox Name="MainTextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" Padding="5,5,15,5" BorderThickness="0" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                      ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" TextChanged="MainTextBox_TextChanged"/>`

For Example: 
What I am trying to achieve is:
First Line Text.

second Line Text

What I am getting is: 
First Line Text.Second Line Text.

Comment: Can you give a minimum example of a text you're trying to paste, the result you expect to see and the result that you're actually seeing?

Comment: Please add that to your question because the formatting won't work in the comment.

Comment: Consider this step:  A sample Text. and press Enter Keys twice and click paste button(content-Second Sample Text). I am expecting as:  A sample Text.\n\nSecond Sample Text. But what i am getting is: A sample Text.Second Sample Text.

Comment: You need to take the new lines into account - please check this question and more importantly the answer - it works great! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312843/winrthow-to-get-textbox-caret-index

Answer (score 0):

A trouble I meet too.

Of course ,`SelectionStart` is the caret position in the TextBox. But the TextBox treat `'\r\n'` as a whole, string type treat it as two alone char.

So, want to use `substring()`, you must find the true index by the given `SelectionStart`.